# Create Filter Condition : Based on two Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Have 2 tables PartnerCountry and ComparerCountry  as below.

Updated Table Structure

```
PartnerTable
Country                 TradeValue
---------------          -----------  
Germany                 |  100
France                  |  2000


ComparerTable   
Country                 TradeValue
---------------          -----------  
India                  |  100
Korea                  |  5000
```

**Old Table Structure**

```
PartnerTable
Germany                France  
---------------        -----------  
100                 |  2000


ComparerTable   
India                 Korea  
---------------       -----------  
100                 |  5000
```

**Condition Required**

```
  case when  (    [Germany]>[India] 
                       or 
                 [Germany]>[Rep. of Korea] ) 

             or
         (
                 [france]>[India] 
                      or 
                  [france]>[Rep. of Korea]) then '1' else '0' end as 'Status'
```

Both the table can have more countries.The value for any country from partner table must be greater than any of the comparison table.

How to be achieve above based on new Table definition? 
I was planning to write dynamic query to prepare the conditions.

Comment: @derloopkat I have edited my question.

Comment: So what's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: I think table definition is incorrect. Countries shouldn't be columns but rows, most of all if there could be more. This forces to get the column schema for the table and use it in the query. Typically that's the reason why a simple query would become into something more complex.

Comment: @derloopkat I have update the table structure, also kept the old structure .

Comment: In your data sample, no country has more value than Korea, so all queries would return no records. Is that the idea? Or you mean comparing same country in both tables?

Comment: Germany has greater value than India or Korea.

Comment: Germany is 100. This is equal to India and less than Korea.

Comment: Atleast 1 record must be greater. In first table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Transform the Data using UNPIVOT, in case you only have the old table structure, then insert the data into the new table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE ParentTable
(
Germany decimal(16,2),
France decimal(16,2)
)



INSERT INTO ParentTable VALUES(100,2000)


CREATE TABLE CompareTable
(
India decimal(16,2),
Korea decimal(16,2)
)

INSERT INTO CompareTable VALUES(100,5000)
```

------------------------NEW TABLE STRUCTURE

```
  CREATE TABLE ParentTable_NEW
    (
    Country varchar(100),
    TradeValue decimal(16,2)
    )


    CREATE TABLE CompareTable_NEW
    (
    Country varchar(100),
    TradeValue decimal(16,2)
    )
```

--------------------USING UNPIVOT WITH DYMANIC COLUMN NAMES IN CASE YOU MAY ADD MORE COUNTRIES PARENT TABLE

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max) 
select @cols = coalesce(@cols+N',', N'') + quotename(c.name) from syscolumns c
inner join sysobjects o on c.id = o.id and o.xtype = 'u'
where o.name = 'ParentTable' -- order by c.colid

declare @query nvarchar(max)  


select @query = N'
select Country,Value
from 
    (
    select ' + @cols + '
    from ParentTable

    ) as cp
    unpivot
    (
    Value for Country in (' + @cols + ')
    ) as up
'

INSERT INTO ParentTable_NEW 
exec sp_executesql @query
```

--------------------USING UNPIVOT WITH DYMANIC COLUMN NAMES IN CASE YOU MAY ADD MORE COUNTRY COMPARE TABLE

```
declare @cols2 nvarchar(max) 
select @cols2 = coalesce(@cols2+N',', N'') + quotename(c.name) from syscolumns c
inner join sysobjects o on c.id = o.id and o.xtype = 'u'
where o.name = 'CompareTable' -- order by c.colid


declare @query2 nvarchar(max)  

select @query2 = N'
select Country,Value
from 
    (
    select ' + @cols2 + '
    from CompareTable

    ) as cp
    unpivot
    (
    Value for Country in (' + @cols2 + ')
    ) as up
'

INSERT INTO CompareTable_NEW 
exec sp_executesql @query2 



----------Final query

SELECT part.Country AS partner_country,
       part.TradeValue AS parter_value,
       comp.Country AS comp_country,
       comp.TradeValue AS comp_value,
       CASE WHEN part.TradeValue > comp.TradeValue THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'Status'
FROM ParentTable_NEW part
CROSS APPLY CompareTable_NEW comp
ORDER BY part.Country
```

Comment: how can it achieved with old table structure

Comment: You should Transform your old table structure to the new Table Structure by using UNPIVOT, first get the Columns to Rows and then insert the data into the new table structure,